# What does 'pushd "/%~1" 2>nul' accomplish in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, pushd

I'm trying to understand the 3 lines in a batch file.  Note that the batch file can accept filenames or a folder name.

```
pushd "%~1" 2>nul
popd
if not errorlevel 1 goto :IsDir
```

I understand what `pushd "%~1"` does but the `2` that follows it baffles me.
Then immediately popping it must be some sort of trick to determine whether the command line argument was a filename or folder, and then branch accordingly using the errorlevel, but how it accomplishes this is a mystery.

Comment: Okay, through testing and reading I figured out that `2>nul` hides error messages spawned by a command.   So when the command line argument is a path name the code make sense. And the code "works" when a filename is supplied, but in my tests if a filename is supplied then the subsequent `popd` changes the current folder to `C:\Windows\System32`, which might cause problems. I still wonder if I'm missing something.

Comment: Thank you to all who replied. Very helpful!  The script  I'm studying is fairly long so not until much later did I investigate the author's use of `setlocal` near the start of the script and `endlocal` at the end.  As a result, when the script ends you're still in the same folder from which you started. Also, from my tests it appears you _remain_ in the original folder even after the `popd` (I used `echo %cd%`  and `DIR` to see where I was after the `popd`).

Answer (score 0):

The reason the test works all because of `pushd`. If your input is a filename, `pushd` failed and `errorlevel` is set to 1. On the other hand, if your input is a directory, then `pushd` success and `errorlevel` is set to 0.

`popd` doesn't change `errorlevel` and is added to revert the side effect of `pushd`. It does have shortcoming that you already encountered: it reverts the effect of the previous *successful* `pushd`. If there is a successful `pushd` before your three lines, and the input is a file, it reverts the that `pushd`.

A better approach is to call `popd` only on the case of success:

```
pushd "%~1" 2>nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
    popd
    goto :IsDir
)
```

(Side note: When tested on Windows 10, pushd writes to standard output. As Mofi pointed out, on Windows XP, it writes to standard error.)

Comment: The error message is written to __stderr__ by `pushd`on Windows XP and therefore `2>nul` is correct and `>nul` does not suppress the error message.

Comment: I tested on Windows 10, where pushd writes to standard error. Please leave the first comment since it might benefit others.

Comment: On Windows 7 SP1 x64 the error message is also output to __stderr__. It looks like best would be to use `>nul 2>&1` to suppress any message output by `pushd`. See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).